# how to access integer keys in R using R package 'hash'

Tags: r

I want to build a hash in R. I installed the hash package in R.

I need to have integer keys. However, I cannot access them .

```
> y <- as.character(seq(0,10,1))
> y
 [1] "0"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"

> h <- hash(key =y, values = 1:11)
> h
<hash> containing 2 key-value pair(s).
  key : 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
  values :  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

When I try to access the keys, it gave me a value of NULL.

```
> h[["0"]]
NULL

 h$"0"
NULL
> h$0
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "h$0"
```

Is there a solution to this ?

Comment: `?hash` says "Keys must be a valid R name, must be a character vector and must not be the empty string, ‘""’."  Numbers are not generally considered valid R names.

Comment: I saw that. That is why I converted the vector y using as.character. But i did is.character(y), which returned TRUE.

Comment: Being character is a necessary, but not sufficient condition for being a valid R name. See [R commands; case sensitivity etc.](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc) in the introductory manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(hash)    
h <- hash(y, 1:11)
> h[["0"]]
    [1] 1
> h["0"]
<hash> containing 1 key-value pair(s).
  0 : 1
> h$"0"
[1] 1
```

Comment: that's the same as mine :)

Comment: I was 30 seconds earlier :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
 h <- hash(y, 1:11)

 h[["2"]]
 [1] 3
```

However, I would just use a named list.  Why the need for the hash package?

```
 h <- as.list(1:11)
 names(h) <- y
 h[["2"]]
 [1] 3
```

Comment: that's same as mine :)

Comment: I was 30 seconds later :)

Comment: should I use a hash or a list, if I have a data vector which is 2^16 long. I may quick access to different their indicies ????

Comment: what is in each of these 2^16 elements?  Are they uniform, will a matrix or array suffice? If so, use that.   The question is what is the specific need for hash?  2^16 is not a reason.

Comment: actually, what i meant was that i need to have 2^16 entries / names. And each contain an integer. I will need to access different entries and change their values from time to time

Comment: It sounds you need a named `list`

Comment: i thought a hash is quicker, because you can easily access them by their keys.

Answer (score 0):

Using `setNames` works:

```
h <- hash(setNames(1:11, 0:10))
h[["0"]]
```

Another option might be to use the `memoise` package.